# How to link a recipe A producing dynamic library with another recipe B?

Tags: yocto

I am trying to link a shared library (libxyz.so) created by recipe A, with an executable created by recipe B by adding -lxyz on the Makefile where it generated the executable.
But I see that recipe A is dependent on recipe B indirectly (through some recipe C), so I can't use DEPENDS flag in .bb file of recipe B.

Is there a way to link my executable with the library libxyz.so?
Also, from my understanding on dynamic libraries, the library must be physically available when the executable is built right?.

Comment: Is is possible to post your recipe A, recipe B and recipe C in question?

Comment: Nope sorry, i am working on some licensed codebase..

Answer (score 0):

You can try to separate B into 2 recipes: library and executable.
Recipe A depend on library B (indirectly). Executable recipe B depends on A and library B.

Makefile of B will be modified accordingly to separate compilation of B library and B executable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I wanted to add my code to libxyz.so, but later created another recipe D with my required code, and linked it with executable of recipe B